# Could not find method include()

Tags: android, testing, gradle, robolectric, robospock

I'm trying to add in testing to my Android app via [RoboSpock](http://robospock.org/). I'm trying to model my project after [their example](https://github.com/Polidea/RoboSpock/tree/master/applications/GradleBasedAndroidApplication). So I have the following structure to my project:

```
src/
    android/
          src/org/myorg/myproject
          build.gradle
    robospock/
          src/
          build.gradle
    gradlew
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

Here's my settings.gradle:

```
include ':android', ':robospock'

project(':android').name = 'estanteApp'
project(':robospock').name = 'estanteApp-robospock-tests'
```

If I run gradle, I get this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/bradrhoads/Documents/src/estante/src/build.gradle' line: 1
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'src'.
>
>   > Could not find method include() for arguments [android, robospock] on root project 'src'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could someone please add robospock as a tag. Not sure if my problem is just a generic Gradle issue or RoboSpock related. But I expect RoboSpock will get used a lot. While many questions will be related to Gradle, Spock and Robolectric, some may be specific to RoboSpock.

Comment: According to the error message, the error occurs in `'/Users/bradrhoads/Documents/src/estante/src/build.gradle' line: 1`. Did you perhaps mix up `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` or something?

Comment: Dang! That's exactly what happened. I ended up pasting the setting.gradle code into the build.gradle file. If you put this in and answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Added `robospock` tag.